# Thread creation scope and the garbage collector

Tags: c#, multithreading, garbage-collection

Does it make any difference for the garbage collector if we declare a thread at method scope rather than at class scope, like:

```
//scenario 1
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        new Thread(()=> /*engine*/) { IsBackground = true }.Start();
    }
}

//scenario 2
public class Bar
{
    private readonly Thread _engineThread = null;

    public Bar()
    {
        _engineThread = new Thread(()=> /*engine*/) { IsBackground = true };
        _engineThread.Start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - in the first approach, the `Thread` object will be eligible for garbage collection as soon as the underlying thread has completed.

In the second approach, if the instance of `Bar` is still *not* eligible for garbage collection, that will prevent the `Thread` object from being garbage collected. I doubt that that will have any impact on the underlying OS thread, mind you.

I wouldn't think about the GC implications though - I'd concentrate on readability. Do you need a reference to that background thread for some reason? If so, go with the second approach so that it's available to you. If you *don't* need it, it would be pointless having it as a field.

Comment: In scenario 1 or scenario 2, could the instances of `Foo` or `Bar` be eligible for garbage collection *before* the end of the thread? If yes, could they be collected before the thread ends?

Comment: @remio: Yes, if nothing holds references to them, they could be garbage collected.